# how to draw a circle using disks, the radii of the disks are 1, while the radius of the circle is $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 6$

Tags: graphics

How to draw a picture like this?

[image: figure]

Suppose the centers of the disks are located on a circle of radius $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 6$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 7):

```
Graphics[Thread[{Reverse[Hue /@ Subdivide[0, 1, 11]], 
   Disk[#, 1] & /@ (RotateRight[(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[6])*CirclePoints[12], 
      5])}]]
```

[image]

Comment: More compact version: `Graphics[MapIndexed[{Hue[1 - #2/12], Disk[#, 1]} &, CirclePoints[{Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[6], 5 π/6}, 12]]]`

Comment: @J.M. Thanks! $\phantom{}$

Answer (score 4):

```
Graphics[Transpose@
  {ColorData["SolarColors"] /@ Subdivide[11],
   Disk /@ CirclePoints[Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[6], 12]}]
```

[image]